# Updating last 2 lines displayed on terminal using shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to build a simple progress bar script which will display a bar as well as current action in progress.

With help of `echo -ne "[||...] Processing ${file_name}\r"` i can display the progress bar as:

> [||||||||............] Processing file1

However i'm expecting output something like this:

> Processing file1
>
> [||||||||............]

Note: Both are seperate lines and i want to update them both as my script progress.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tput cuu 2` to move the cursor up two lines, and `tput el` to clear the current line:

```
while sleep 1
do
    tput el; date
    tput el; echo "$RANDOM"
    tput cuu 2
done
```

This will produce two changing lines of e.g.

```
Thu Jul 23 17:50:46 PDT 2015
23676
```

Comment: The solution works fine for what i asked for :-) can u also suggest how to erase & reprint? because with current solution the problem is If it prints `barrr` first and next to print is `foo` it prints `foorr`

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by [@that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) makes an assumption that a 2-character padding is enough to cover differences in `$RANDOM` (a [nonstandard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) [bash-specific](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables) feature which returns from 1 to 5 digits).

That can be accommodated using the terminal capability which clears from the cursor position to the end of the line.  In both cases, the scripts assume that the messages are short enough that line-wrapping is not a problem (the OP's question gave an example with that possibility):

```
#!/bin/bash
UP1="$(tput cuu 1)"
EL0="$(tput el)"
while sleep 1
do
    date
    printf '%s%s\r%s' "$RANDOM" "$EL0" "$UP1"
done
```